# How to install dataprep.eda to Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda, conda

Does anyone have instructions on how to add the dataprep.eda library to Anaconda, within PyCharm.
I've attempted downloading the project and then doing it manually as well as adding a channel to Anaconda. Adding a channel gives a 404 error. Attempting to do the install manually gives the output below:

conda install /Python/libs/dataprep-0.2.8.tar
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- /python/libs/dataprep-0.2.8.tar

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this might not work with the community edition that I am running. I'm not sure if this is the case or not but am still searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this on Jupyter:

```
pip install dataprep
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c conda-forge dataprep
```